# Why does not this code allow upload of audio files?

Tags: php, audio, file-upload

I want to allow the user to upload audio files to my website, but after writing the code it turns out that it is failing to upload audio files. I have tried other filetypes and it's working for them.

Here's the HTML form:

```
<body>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="audioFile"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Audio" name="save_audio"/>
</form>
```

And here's the php code:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['save_audio']) && $_POST['save_audio']=="Upload Audio") { $dir='uploads/'; $audio_path=$dir.basename($_FILES['audioFile']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['audioFile']['tmp_name'],$audio_path))
{
    echo 'uploaded successfully.';
}else 
    echo 'Upload Failed';

} ?>
```

With other file types am receiving the echo "Uploaded successfully" but when I try an audio file i get "Upload Failed".

Comment: Did you check the file error `$_FILES['audioFile']['error']`?

Comment: Please don't use $_POST, $_GET, $_REQUEST without sanitizing the inputs. You can use PHP Frameworks for safety and ease. Like CodeIgniter, Laravel.

Comment: No i did not, thanks for the reminder